# How can I connect Android to my PC for backups?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb-drivers

When I plug in my Android into a WIn7 or Win8 machine, they tell me that the device is unrecognized.  Yet the manual that came with the Android clearly shows this being done.  This is an RCA Viking Pro.

Question:  Are there drivers that need to be loaded on the PC first?  If so, where can I get them?

Comment: This is a problem in Windows, you can do it manually. Check this website, http://windowsreport.com/windows-10-doesnt-recognize-android/ This should help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found in this article:

[Fix: Windows 10 Doesn’t Recognize Android Phone](http://windowsreport.com/windows-10-doesnt-recognize-android/)

Excerpt:

[image]

[image]